# How to disable wrapping completely in mutt?

Tags: mutt

I'm currently working with `mutt` to get it to display HTML mail properly. I've set up `auto_view` and a `w3m` invocation in the mailcap, and this works fine.

However, the URLs for links in received mail are often longer than the width of my terminal window. This makes clicking them inconvenient, because they become split across multiple lines, and I have to manually reconstruct the original URL before I can copy it to the browser.

I've set `$markers` to off, which successfully removes the plus sign marking a wrapped line. However, mutt is still wrapping the lines on its own (presumably just by echoing `\n`, since that's what I get on a copy), so it's still inconvenient to get the link.

Is there a way to tell mutt to disable wrapping completely, and just let the terminal emulator handle it? This would allow the links to be copied in one operation. There doesn't seem to be such an option for the `$wrap` variable; I've tried setting `$wrap` to far wider than the terminal width, but this doesn't work.

Comment: What does `$wrap=0` do for you?

Comment: This is what `extract_url` was written for.

Comment: @tink 0 is the default, isn't it? In any case, it's the same behavior, unhelpful.

Comment: @jasonwryan Sadly, the machine running mutt is remote of the machine running my browser, and can't access it. Copy-and-paste from the terminal emulator is the only good way I've found to open a URL.

Comment: Well, it would still make sense to write a macro to use extract_url to write the URLs to a file that you can then open locally...

Comment: Could be a good option. I've since discovered that copying the URLs with newlines included still lets them paste correctly into a browser, so it may be the least inconvenience just to deal with the current situation.

Comment: Can someone provide a link to the `exact_url` solution?  I'm failing to find anything clear about it.  Otherwise the `set marker = no` approach has worked for me when the terminal recognizes and opens links in the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

For my following answer, I put

```
set mailcap_path = "~/.mutt/mailcap"
```

in my `muttrc` file and the following settings should be put in the `mailcap` file, i.e., in `~/.mutt/mailcap`.

This is more related to `w3m` instead of `mutt`, to be short, you should set:

```
text/html; w3m -I %{charset} -T text/html -dump -cols 1000; copiousoutput
```

since the default vaule of `cols` with `dump` option on is around 80, which cuts off long urls.

However to see more information about url, I suggest preview as markdown format:

```
text/html; iconv -t 'UTF-8' -f %{charset} | pandoc -f html -t gfm-raw_html --wrap=none; copiousoutput
```

Comment: I put that in my `.muttrc` but now I just get an error `text/html: unknown command`. What exactly are we supposed to do here by "you should set"?

Comment: I added the instruction in my answer just now.

Answer (score 0):

In Debian, I fix this as follows

```
sudo apt-get install urlview

cat << EOF > ~/.urlview
REGEXP (((http|https|ftp|gopher)|mailto)[.:][^ >"\t]*|www\.[-a-z0-9.]+)[^ .,;\t>">\):]
COMMAND echo %s > ~/url.txt
EOF
```

Now when you open `mutt`, choose an email and then press `ctrl+b`. This will open a menu listing all of the URLs extracted from the email.

Use the arrow keys to select the URL that you want to open, and press the `enter` key.

Close mutt, and you'll see the URL has been written to the file `url.txt` in your `$HOME` directory. Now it's easy to copy & paste with `cat`.

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mutt#Viewing_URLs_in_a_web_browser